# User name of currently logged in user or the program identity if there's none (Owin IIS/self-hosted)

Tags: windows, asp.net-identity, windows-authentication, owin, claims-based-identity

I'm doing a more generic logging library that's running in IIS (Owin) or as a self-hosted (Owin) Windows Service. One piece of logging information I would like to include is in order of preference:

1. The name of the authenticated (logged in) user.
2. If 1. isn't available, the account under which the process is running. This could be the one under which the IIS application pool is running or the account under which the Windows Service is running.

Impersonation isn't important currently and I am mainly interested on a situation where IIS has Windows Authentication on/off or OAuth is used and it ran as a domain-joined machine (developer/CI machines can be just "something" and aren't acccessed from outside). The trouble I see is that there are many ways to acquire this information, but which one does work in the scenarios I describe? I found a very helpful blog post [Getting A Users Username in ASP.NET](http://richhewlett.com/2011/02/15/getting-a-users-username-in-asp-net/) by *Rich Hewlett* where especially the follwing point answers partially this question

```
Scenario 2: Windows Authentication in IIS, impersonation off.
+------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
| HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name   | MYDOMAIN\USER1   |
| HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated          | True             |
| HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name               | MYDOMAIN\USER1   |
| System.Environment.UserName                          | ASPNET           |
| Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name | COMPUTER1\ASPNET |
+------------------------------------------------------+------------------+
```

Here, it looks like, I just need to check if `IsAuthenticated` is true and if so, take the username from `LogonUserIdentity` and if not, the from current `WindowsIdentity`. This won't necessarily work on self-hosted Owin (I haven't checked). Furthermore, I see there has been a lot of things happening around claims lately.

So, I'm looking for something simpler, like

```
//This may be empty...
var userId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name);

//It looks like there's always something here...
var userId2 = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name);

//Or should this work...
string userId = string.Empty;
if(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    userId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name;
}
else
{
    userId = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
}
```

and hopefully will be covered when someone decides to switch Windows Authentication on IIS on or off or change it to OAuth. In fact, preferably on self-hosted Owin application too.

Comment: `ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name` - try this

Comment: Hmm, it feels the same as ``ClaimsTypes.Name``. In any event, my problem is that it's difficult to ascertain some type of code really works as intended, say, when I deploy it to a domain joined IIS or run as a service accepting calls from outside. Thus far I haven't managed to find a matrix that would show API return values in various environment combinations.

Comment: Perhaps if you rephrase your question to say what exactly are you trying to do with these users, it'll make easier to answer. At the moment I'm slightly lost of what you are trying to acheive

Comment: You are right. I rewrote the whole question, hopefully it's much clearer as of now.

Comment: Yes, that's much better, thank you. I think `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` is closest to what you need. And I don't think there is a better way to get what you need.

Comment: I edited the question a bit further with the if-clause. It looks like the ``IsAuthenticated`` means what it says in the tin and if it isn't there, I can grab the identity the thread is running under, which will be the same as as user's in case there is no authentication or the program thread is being impersonated. Though I'm not entirely sure of this... Sorry for the inconvenience of sporadic edits.